# This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below - XML error when rendering

Tags: xml, spring, jsf

I meet the problem like this:

After the session time out, I call an AJAX request to the server and it redirects me to the login page. I try to login again. Then, it appears:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below

After refreshing the page, my web run correctly. What is the reason of this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Answer depends on authentication framework you're using. JAAS? JASPIC? Spring Security? Basically, its mistake is that it re-executed the Ajax postback request as if it's a synchronous postback rather than performing a plain redirect to that URL. However, how to fix that depends on the authentication framework used.

Comment: My best guess - because after successful login, your server responds to the ajax request that you made earlier. Its the browser behaviour to show the error you stated, when they don't know how to render the XML that your server sent. You should fix this at your server. Differentiate the AJAX request from normal GET request.